# Google Chrome Extension : Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been looking for an answer for almost a week now, but having read all the stackoverflow items i can't seem to find a solution that is working for me.

The error that i'm having is :

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. lastError:30 set   lastError:30 dispatchOnDisconnect messaging:277
```

folder layout :

```
img
   developer_icon.png
js
   sidebar.js
   main.js
   jquery-2.0.3.js
manifest.json
```

my the manifest.json file looks something like this (it is version 2) :`

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "./img/developer_icon.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
{      
  "matches": ["*://*/*"],
  "js": ["./js/sidebar.js"],   
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],

"background" : {
    "scripts" : ["./js/main.js","./js/jquery-2.0.3.js"] 
},
```

I want to handle the user clicking the extension icon so i could inject a sidebar in the existing website (because the extension i would like to develop requires that amount of space). So in main.js :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {          
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){        
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                //Selected tab id
                tab.id,                         
                //Params inside a object data
                {callFunction: "toggleSidebar"}, 
                //Optional callback function
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

and in sidebar.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req,sender,sendResponse){
    console.log("sidebar handling request");
    toggleSidebar();
});
```

but i'm never able to see the console.log in my console because of the error. Does someone know what i did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code works as expected. Do you get any message on the webpage log. Have you checked if the content script is actually injected ? (Make sure to reload any open page after you deploy your extension.)

Comment: everything goes as planned, but when i call the chrome.tabs.sendMessage(...) function, the error occurs. Where can i check if the script is injected?

Comment: When your content script receives a message it prints something on the console. So: 1. Open a new tab (e.g. `www.google.com`). 2. Click the browser-action button for your extension. 3. Still on the newly opened tab pres `Ctrl+Shilf+I` to open the developer console. 4. If the content script is injected and received the message from your background page, you will see something printed on the console. BTW, **chrome.tabs.getSelected** is deprecated and useless, since you have the selected tab passed to you from the `onClicked` listener anyway.

Comment: it is loaded, and now it works. I don't know if i changed anything.. 
But thanks for wanting to help me out! I appreciate the help!

Comment: NP ! Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone landing on this page while facing a similar problem:

OP's code does work as expected !

A couple of minor remarks:

1. The callback for **[chrome.tabs.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)** is optional, so there is no need to define one if you don't intend to call it on the receiving end. I.e. the following is reduntant:

   `...`
   `//Optional callback function`
   `function(response) {`
       `console.log(response);`
   `}`
2. **chrome.tabs.getSelected** has beed deprecated and should not be used. Use **[chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)** instead.
3. In this particular case, the call to **chrome.tabs.getSelected** is reduntant, since **[chrome.browserAction.onClicked](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)** callback passes the active tab as an argument.